# How to sum of 2 rows based on condition in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

How to merge two rows to single row with sum?

This is what am getting now...

```
LeaveTypeId   LeaveTypeFName       day
---------------------------------------
 1            Casual Leave         9.0
 3            SickLeave            3.0
10            Festival             4.0
11            LOP                 15.0
14            National Holiday     4.0
18            P-SickLeave          1.0
19            P-Casual Leave       3.0
```

but my  expected output  is

```
LeaveTypeId   LeaveTypeFName           day
--------------------------------------------
 1            Casual Leave(All)        12.0
 3            SickLeave(All)            4.0
10            Festival                  4.0
11            LOP                      15.0
14            National Holiday          4.0
```

This is my SQL query

```
select  
   b.LeaveTypeId,LeaveTypeFName,
   SUM(case when LeaveStatus = 'FullDay' 
               then DATEDIFF(day, FromDate, ToDate) + 1 
               else 0.5 
       end) as 'day'
from 
   LeaveEntries a
join 
   LeaveTypes b on a.LeaveTypeId = b.LeaveTypeId
where 
   EmployeeId = '3862'
group by 
   LeaveTypeFName, b.LeaveTypeId
```

this is my LeaveEntries Table

```
LeaveEntryId    LeaveTypeId LeaveStatus EmployeeId  FromDate         ToDate         
  19              3            FullDay     3484     2013-02-06      2013-02-09  
  21              1            HalfDay     3484     2013-03-07      2013-03-07
```

Comment: You better show table schema and sample data.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Case Statement` to do this.

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN LeaveTypeFName LIKE '%Casual Leave%' THEN 'Casual Leave(All)'
         WHEN LeaveTypeFName LIKE '%SickLeave%' THEN 'SickLeave (All)'
         WHEN LeaveTypeFName LIKE '%Festival%' THEN 'Festival'
         WHEN LeaveTypeFName LIKE '%LOP%' THEN 'LOP'
         WHEN LeaveTypeFName LIKE '%National Holiday%' THEN 'National Holiday'
       END LeaveTypeFName,
       Sum([day]) [day]
FROM   result
GROUP  BY CASE
            WHEN LeaveTypeFName LIKE '%Casual Leave%' THEN 'Casual Leave(All)'
            WHEN LeaveTypeFName LIKE '%SickLeave%' THEN 'SickLeave (All)'
            WHEN LeaveTypeFName LIKE '%Festival%' THEN 'Festival'
            WHEN LeaveTypeFName LIKE '%LOP%' THEN 'LOP'
            WHEN LeaveTypeFName LIKE '%National Holiday%' THEN 'National Holiday'
          END
```

Comment: I doubt about this,because as per expected output user want group by LeaveTypeFName only, not ID.

Comment: @AK47 - yeah you are right but, am not sure he got those `LeaveTypeId` in result.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this,

the idea is just to take your current result as it is, just remove '`P-`' from `LeaveTypeFName` & then again group by result. Hope this work!

```
;With CTE as
(
    select  
       b.LeaveTypeId
      ,Case When b.LeaveTypeId in(18,19) 
              Then Replace(LeaveTypeFName,'P-','') 
              Else LeaveTypeFName 
       End as LeaveTypeFName
      ,SUM(case when LeaveStatus = 'FullDay' 
              Then DATEDIFF(day, FromDate, ToDate) + 1 
              Else 0.5 
            end) as 'day'
    from LeaveEntries a
    join LeaveTypes b on a.LeaveTypeId = b.LeaveTypeId
    where EmployeeId = '3862'
    group by LeaveTypeFName, b.LeaveTypeId
)
Select max(LeaveTypeId) as LeaveTypeId
        ,LeaveTypeFName
        ,Sum(day)
     from CTE
group by LeaveTypeFName
```